# Solution of the differential equation $\ddot{x}(t)+\sin(\omega t)x(t)=cos[\eta(t)]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, special-functions, stochastic-calculus

The differential equation:

$$\ddot{x}(t)+\sin(\omega t)x(t)=cos(\eta t)$$
has an analytical solution involving Mathieu functions.
This is valid if both $\omega$ and $\eta$ are constant.
Suppose the term $\eta$ is a normal distribuited random variable $\eta(t)$ with mean $\mu$ equal to zero and variance $\sigma^2$. How changes the solution?
Or better: Is it possible to find analytically the spectrum of $x(t)$? Thanks